# SQL Server database + strange things

Tags: sql-server, multiple-instances

I have 3 instance of database named X. Each of them is on the other server. Now...
Let's look on the some table named Orders.

- In X_1 and X_2 size of this table is about 500MB with 1 000 000 records.
- In X_3 size of this table is about 1,5 GB with 1 000 000 records.

Why? What is wrong. I have made shrink on each database.

I'm confused :-)!

Comment: How do you determine the size of the database? I mean using what code?

Comment: I am working with MS SQL Server Management Studio. Right clik on properties and here we go.

Answer (score 0):

are there any configuration differences in the data bases? If not there, then check for differences in file systems (such as block size, device architecture, etc).

Comment: What configuration should I check?

Answer (score 0):

look and see if what recovery mode each database is in (right-click database, properties, options).  i'm betting that the third database is in full recovery mode and the other two are in simple.

Comment: hmm... ok.  if you compared the files, is the database file larger, or the log file, or both?